# On what basis music apps categories the trending songs?

Tags: spotify

I am designing a music web app.
In that, I want to display the trending songs
Are there any criteria to display the trending songs as Spotify or Gaana does?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the Spotify Web API? What language are your coding in? You should add more info/code samples so people aren't guessing.

There isn't an API endpoint to specifically 'get the top tracks on Spotify'.

But...you could use the ID of their Top 50 playlist and pull in the tracks from that: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF

The Id is `37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF` so,

`GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF`

source: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist/

Comment: I am not using Spotify API I have created my own API and fetching songs from my database. Now the requirement is to display the trending songs so I am finding the parameters means on what basis I can display or fetch the trending songs.